# Spring filter chain get stopped when authenticate failed

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-security, jwt

Okay, let's say I have a JwtAuthenticationFilter:

```
public class JwtAuthenticationFilter extends OncePerRequestFilter {

    @Autowired
    //blabla

    @Override
    protected void doFilterInternal(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, FilterChain filterChain) throws ServletException, IOException {
        String jwt = extract(request);

        if (StringUtils.hasText(jwt) && tokenVerifier.verify(jwt)) {
            UserCredential user = getUserCredential(jwt, getTokenSigningKey());
            UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken auth = new UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken(user, null, buildAuthorities(user));
            SecurityContextHolder.getContext().setAuthentication(auth);
        }

        filterChain.doFilter(request, response);
    }
}
```

And the JwtAuthenticationEntryPoint:

```
@Component
public class JwtAuthenticationEntryPoint implements AuthenticationEntryPoint {

    @Override
    public void commence(HttpServletRequest httpServletRequest, HttpServletResponse httpServletResponse,
            AuthenticationException e) throws IOException {
        log.error("Responding with unauthorized error.");
        httpServletResponse.setStatus(HttpServletResponse.SC_UNAUTHORIZED);
        httpServletResponse.getWriter().write("Unauthorized");
    }
}
```

Then the WebSecurityConfig:

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
@EnableGlobalMethodSecurity(
        securedEnabled = true,
        jsr250Enabled = true,
        prePostEnabled = true
)
public class WebSecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    private static final String[] AUTH_WHITELIST = {
            "/v3/api-docs/**"
    };
    
    @Autowired
    private UserDetailsServiceImpl userDetailsService;

    @Autowired
    private JwtAuthenticationEntryPoint unauthorizedHandler;

    @Bean
    public JwtAuthenticationFilter jwtAuthenticationFilter() {
        return new JwtAuthenticationFilter();
    }

    @Override
    public void configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder authenticationManagerBuilder) throws Exception {
        authenticationManagerBuilder
                .userDetailsService(userDetailsService)
                .passwordEncoder(passwordEncoder());
    }

    @Bean(BeanIds.AUTHENTICATION_MANAGER)
    @Override
    public AuthenticationManager authenticationManagerBean() throws Exception {
        return super.authenticationManagerBean();
    }

    @Bean
    public PasswordEncoder passwordEncoder() {
        return new BCryptPasswordEncoder();
    }

    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {

        ExpressionUrlAuthorizationConfigurer<HttpSecurity>.ExpressionInterceptUrlRegistry registry = http
                .cors().and().csrf().disable()
                .exceptionHandling()
                .authenticationEntryPoint(unauthorizedHandler)
                .and()
                .sessionManagement()
                .sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS)
                .and()
                .authorizeRequests()
                // No need authentication.
                .antMatchers(AUTH_WHITELIST).permitAll();

        registry.anyRequest().authenticated();

        // Add our custom JWT security filter
        http.addFilterBefore(jwtAuthenticationFilter(), UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter.class);
    }
}
```

It's completely fine. Whenever I make a call to any API (except in white list) without token, the

```
commence(HttpServletRequest httpServletRequest, HttpServletResponse httpServletResponse, AuthenticationException e)
```

will be executed, I will see 401 response. Totally fine.
BUT the point here is, after the method commence is executed, then the filter chain will be terminated. I mean any filters left will NOT be executed. How can I make the chain executed continually even the method commence get executed? Or any other JWT security mechanism to not stop filter chain even authenticate failed?

Comment: you always set the request to be unauthorized, so there is no need to continue the filter chain, because your filter failed. My guess is that if you would not set the status to unauthorized, it wuold continue

Comment: which method do you mention?